# How to set project references programmatically in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How can I set project references programmatically for an existing project in Eclipse? I know how to do it when creating a new project, but once the project is created, it doesn't have any methods for setting references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `IProjectDescription` from the `IProject` object for the project using the `getDescription()` method and call the `setReferencedProjects(IProject [])` method. There is also a `getReferencedProjects()` method.

You need to call `setDescription` on the `IProject` again after changing it.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I only needed to call `setDescription` on the project afterwards.

Comment: Updated answer to include that